# Cloth Simulation folllowing a certain path? (Falling Leaf)

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I want to animate a falling leaf that follows a particular path. I want to control the trajectory instead of letting it fly around randomly. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign all vertices to a vertex group `PIN` with a small weight. Add a cloth sim, set Shape > Pin Group to `PIN`, increase or decrease *Stiffness* to control the influence. Of course animate the object's location and rotation to control where the cloth is dragged.

Comment: oh yes! now we're talking :) That works perfectly fine with follow path constraint.

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiiice !!! love that!